# splitting surnames from fullnames

Tags: r, string

I've used this:

```
String <- unlist(str_split(Invname,"[ ]",n=2))
```

To split the names that I have into Surnames and First Names, since the surnames come first. But I cannot figure out how to reassign the split `Invname` into two lists, so that I can use only the surnames for the rest of my project. Right now I have this:

```
" [471] "KRUEGER"                                 "MARCUS"         "
```

And I would like to have the left side only assigned to a new variable, so that I can work further with mining the surnames for information.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post the output of `dput(head(Invname))` at the end of your question? Also show expected output.

Comment: If you post some of your data, can give this in an example but `dplyr::separate` should help here

Answer (score 2):

Using the data in [nate.edwinton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53903037/spliting-surenames-from-fullnames/53903195#53903195), there is no need to `unlist`.

```
Invnames <- c("Krueger Markus","Doe John","Tatum Jayson")

String <- stringr::str_split(Invnames, "[ ]", n = 2)
Surnames <- sapply(String, '[', 1)
Firstnames <- sapply(String, '[', 2)
data.frame(Surnames, Firstnames)
#  Surnames Firstnames
#1  Krueger     Markus
#2      Doe       John
#3    Tatum     Jayson
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it would be easier to help if you provided some data. Anyway, here might be a solution:

Assuming that `Invnames` is a vector of where for every first name there is (exactly) one last name, you could do the following

```
# data
Invnames <- c("Krueger Markus","Doe John","Tatum Jayson")
# extraction
String <- unlist(stringr::str_split(Invnames,"[ ]",n=2))
# saving first and last names
lastNames <- String[seq(1,length(String),2)]
firstNames <- String[seq(2,length(String),2)]
# yields
> cbind(lastNames,firstNames)
     lastNames firstNames
[1,] "Krueger" "Markus"  
[2,] "Doe"     "John"    
[3,] "Tatum"   "Jayson"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample data and a suggested solution. Data modified from @Rui Barradas' answer:

```
Invnames <- c("Krueger.$Markus","Doe.John","Tatum.Jayson")
sapply(strsplit(Invnames,"\\W"),"[")
```

Answer (score 1):

Again using data from an earlier answer with `dplyr` this time

```
library(tidyverse)

Invnames <- c("Krueger Markus","Doe John","Tatum Jayson")
Invnames <- data.frame(Invnames)

Invnames %>%
  separate(Invnames, c('Surname', 'FirstName'), sep=" ")

 Surname FirstName
1 Krueger    Markus
2     Doe      John
3   Tatum    Jayson
```

Answer (score 1):

With `base R`, we can make use of `read.table/read.csv` to separate the string into columns

```
read.table(text = Invnames, header = FALSE, col.names = c("Surnames", "Firstnames"))
#  Surnames Firstnames
#1  Krueger     Markus
#2      Doe       John
#3    Tatum     Jayson
```

#### data

```
Invnames <- c("Krueger Markus","Doe John","Tatum Jayson")
```

Answer (score 0):

If only names were so straightforward! If there were few complications between strings then yes the answers below are good options. In my experience with name lists we get hyphenated names (both in "first" and "last"), "Middle" names, Titles and shortened name versions (Dr., Mr, Md), and many other variants. I first try to clean the strings before any splitting.

Here is just one idea using dplyr (explicit code provided for clarity)

```
Invnames <- c("Krueger Markus","Doe John","Tatum Jayson", "Taylor - Cline Jeff", "Davis - Freud Melvin- John")

df <- as.data.frame(Invnames, Invnames = Invnames) %>% 
mutate(Invnames2 = gsub("- ","-",Invnames)) %>% 
mutate(Invnames2 = gsub(" -","-",Invnames2)) %>% 
mutate(surname = gsub(" .*", "", Invnames2))
```